# Need to fetch text of a span class inside iframe in playwright javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, playwright

[Image of HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEncw.png)

Can someone explain me how to get the text of the start game button which is present inside iFrame in Playwright JavaScript ,

I tried using below code but that is not working for me

````
        console.log(frame)
        // const text= await frame.locator("//div[text()='Start Game']").textContent();
        // console.log(text);```
````

Comment: Are You Following The CORS Policy? That Is The Webpage And Iframe From The Same Domain? If Not You Cannot Get The Span Details

Comment: Yes both webpage and iframe are of same domain

Answer (score 0):

Use `frameLocator` function to access the content within iFrame.

```
const btnStart = page.frameLocator('#external-app').locator('text=Start Game');
await btnStart.click();
```

More details: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator

To access the value or text, you can use `page.innerText()` or `page.inputValue()`.

More infos here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-input-value